# Tablayout on swipe not refreshing in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, sharedpreferences, android-tablayout

I am implementing `tablayout` using `view pager` and in my scenario I have two `tab`. In my first `tab` I have add data which store in `share preference`. and when I move to second tab then data should be retrieve from `share preference` and show in `listview`. When I add the data from my first `tab` then data is added successfully but not show in my second `tab` means I have to close my application and again restart the app so that I can see saved the detail which saved from my first `tab`.
Below is my Activity code.

```
    public class FragmentExample extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;

    @BindView(R.id.tabCountryState)
    TabLayout tabCountryState;

    @BindView(R.id.viewPager)
    ViewPager viewPager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment_example);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);


        setViewPager();
        setTabIcon();
        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);


        tabCountryState.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                Log.e("Current tab is ", "===>  " + tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            }
        });
    }

    private void setViewPager() {
        // set Adaapter.
        viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), FragmentExample.this);
        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
        tabCountryState.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    // set custom icon to tab in Tablayout.
    private void setTabIcon() {
        // First Tab
        View firstTab = (View) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_icon_first, null);
        TextView tvFirsIcon = ButterKnife.findById(firstTab, R.id.tvFirsIcon);
        tvFirsIcon.setText("First Tab");
        tabCountryState.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(firstTab);

        // First Tab
        View secondTab = (View) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_icon_second, null);
        TextView tvSecondIcon = ButterKnife.findById(secondTab, R.id.tvSecondIcon);
        tvSecondIcon.setText("Second Tab");
        tabCountryState.getTabAt(1).setCustomView(secondTab);
    }

    public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        private Context context;
        private FirstFragment firstFragment;
        private SecondFragment secondFragment;

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context mainActivity) {
            super(fm);
            context = mainActivity;
            new FirstFragment();
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    firstFragment = new FirstFragment();
                    return firstFragment;

                case 1:
                    secondFragment = new SecondFragment();
                    return secondFragment;

                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return " " + position;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my FirstFragment in which I have added the data into share preference.

```
    public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {

    private View v;
    @BindView(R.id.btnSubmit)
    Button btnSubmit;

    @BindView(R.id.edtCityName)
    EditText edtCityName;

    @BindView(R.id.spStateName)
    Spinner spStateName;

    private Unbinder unbinder;
    private ArrayList<String> alStateName;
    private ArrayList<AllStateCityModel> alAllStateCity;
    private SpinnerStateAdapter spinnerAdapter;
    private int spinnerPosition;
    private String strCityName, strSpinnerValue;


    @OnClick(R.id.btnSubmit)
    public void submit(View view) {

        if (spinnerPosition !=0) {

            strCityName = edtCityName.getText().toString().trim();
            alAllStateCity = SessinoManager.getCityList(getActivity());

            if (strCityName.length() > 0) {
                alAllStateCity.get(spinnerPosition).getAlCityName().add(new CityStateModel(strCityName));
            } else {
            }

            // Save new data to Session.
            SessinoManager.saveCityList(getActivity(), alAllStateCity);

            SecondFragment.cityAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Detail saved successfully ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            edtCityName.setText("");

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please select state", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
        unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, v);

        // arraylist checking if data is available into session.
        if(SessinoManager.getCityList(getActivity()).size()>0){
            Log.e("First fragment "," if condition ");
            alAllStateCity = SessinoManager.getCityList(getActivity());

            alStateName = new ArrayList<>();
            for(int i=0;i<alAllStateCity.size();i++){
                alStateName.add(alAllStateCity.get(i).getStrStateName());
            }
            setStateSpinner();
        }else{
            loadArraylist();
            setStateSpinner();
        }
        return v;
    }

    private void setStateSpinner() {

        spStateName.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                spinnerPosition = i;
                spinnerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                strSpinnerValue = alStateName.get(i).toString().trim();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
            }
        });

        spinnerAdapter = new SpinnerStateAdapter(getActivity(), alStateName);
        spStateName.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
    }

    private void loadArraylist() {

        alAllStateCity = new ArrayList<>();
        alStateName = new ArrayList<>();


        alStateName.add(0, "Select State");
        alStateName.add("Gujarat");
        alStateName.add("Maharashtra");
        alStateName.add("Madhya Pradesh");


        for (int i = 0; i < alStateName.size(); i++) {
            alAllStateCity.add(new AllStateCityModel(alStateName.get(i), alAllStateCity.size(), new ArrayList<CityStateModel>()));
        }

        SessinoManager.saveCityList(getActivity(), alAllStateCity);
    }

    @Override public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        unbinder.unbind();

        Log.e("First fragment "," on destroy");
    }
}
```

Here is my SecondFragment in which I have to get saved detail from `Share preference`.

```
    public class SecondFragment extends Fragment {

    private View v;
    private Unbinder unbinder;

    @BindView(R.id.lvCityList)
    ListView lvCityList;

    @BindView(R.id.spinnerStateName)
    Spinner spinnerStateName;

    private ArrayList<AllStateCityModel> alAllStateCity;
    private ArrayList<CityStateModel> alCityName;
    private ArrayList<String> alStateName;
    private int spinnerPosition;
    private SpinnerStateAdapter spinnerAdapter;
    private ArrayList<String> alCity;
    public static CityAdapter cityAdapter;
    private Context context;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);
        unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, v);

        context = getActivity();

        loadArrayList(context);

        Log.e("onCreateView", "onCreateView");

        return v;
    }
    private void loadArrayList(Context context) {

        alCityName = new ArrayList<>();
        alStateName = new ArrayList<>();
        alAllStateCity = SessinoManager.getCityList(context);

        for (int j = 0; j < alAllStateCity.size(); j++) {
//            Log.e("State name  ","  =========================> "+allPlayList.get(j).getStrStateName());

            // get state name from session
            alStateName.add(alAllStateCity.get(j).getStrStateName());

            setSpinner(context);
        }
    }

    private void setSpinner(Context context) {

        spinnerAdapter = new SpinnerStateAdapter(context, alStateName);
        spinnerStateName.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);

        spinnerStateName.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                spinnerPosition = i;
                spinnerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                setList(spinnerPosition);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void setList(int position) {

        alCityName = alAllStateCity.get(position).getAlCityName();
        alCity = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < alCityName.size(); i++) {
//                Log.e("City name "," !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"+alCityName.get(i).getStrCity());
            alCity.add(alCityName.get(i).getStrCity());
        }

        cityAdapter = new CityAdapter(context, alCity);
        lvCityList.setAdapter(cityAdapter);
        cityAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

}
```

And I am saving data into `Share preference` which is given below.

```
    public class SessinoManager {

    private static final String CITY_PREFERENCE = "city_preference";

    // Save data to share preference.
    public static void saveCityList(Context context, ArrayList<AllStateCityModel> alAllPlayList) {
        try {
            SharedPreferences settings;
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

            settings = context.getSharedPreferences(CITY_PREFERENCE,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            editor = settings.edit();

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String jsonUsers = gson.toJson(alAllPlayList);
            editor.putString("all_play_list", jsonUsers);
            editor.commit();

            // Check to save data into share preferent
            for(int j=0;j<alAllPlayList.size();j++){
                Log.e("State name ","----------------------"+alAllPlayList.get(j).getStrStateName());
                ArrayList<CityStateModel> cityName = alAllPlayList.get(j).getAlCityName();
                for(int i=0;i<cityName.size();i++){
                    Log.e("cityName "," in session ==> "+cityName.get(i).getStrCity());
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static ArrayList<AllStateCityModel> getCityList(Context context)
    {
        SharedPreferences settings;
        List<AllStateCityModel> users = new ArrayList<>();

        settings = context.getSharedPreferences(CITY_PREFERENCE,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        if (settings.contains("all_play_list"))
        {
            String jsonUsers = settings.getString("all_play_list", null);
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            AllStateCityModel[] userItems = gson.fromJson(jsonUsers,AllStateCityModel[].class);

            users = Arrays.asList(userItems);
            users= new ArrayList<AllStateCityModel>(users);
        }
        return (ArrayList<AllStateCityModel>) users;
    }
}
```

When I add new city detail into first tab then data is data successfully but when I swipe or move to next then data is not displaying and I have to restart whole application to get updated data from `Share preference.` Kindly help me to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the problem by implementing below method `setUserVisibleHint`.

```
    public class SecondFragment extends Fragment {

    private View v;
    private Unbinder unbinder;

    @BindView(R.id.lvCityList)
    ListView lvCityList;

    @BindView(R.id.spinnerStateName)
    Spinner spinnerStateName;

    private ArrayList<AllStateCityModel> alAllStateCity;
    private ArrayList<CityStateModel> alCityName;
    private ArrayList<String> alStateName;
    private int spinnerPosition;
    private SpinnerStateAdapter spinnerAdapter;
    private ArrayList<String> alCity;
    public static CityAdapter cityAdapter;
    private Context context;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);
        unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, v);

        context = getActivity();

        loadArrayList(context);

//        Log.e("onCreateView", "onCreateView");

        return v;
    }

    private void loadArrayList(Context context) {

        alCityName = new ArrayList<>();
        alStateName = new ArrayList<>();
        alAllStateCity = SessinoManager.getCityList(context);

        for (int j = 0; j < alAllStateCity.size(); j++) {
//            Log.e("State name  ","  =========================> "+allPlayList.get(j).getStrStateName());

            // get state name from session
            alStateName.add(alAllStateCity.get(j).getStrStateName());

            setSpinner(context);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        Log.e("setUserVisibleHint","setUserVisibleHint  "+isVisibleToUser);

        if(isVisibleToUser==true){
            loadArrayList(context);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean getUserVisibleHint() {
        Log.e("getUserVisibleHint","getUserVisibleHint  "+super.getUserVisibleHint());
        return super.getUserVisibleHint();

    }

    private void setSpinner(Context context) {

        spinnerAdapter = new SpinnerStateAdapter(context, alStateName);
        spinnerStateName.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);

        spinnerStateName.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                spinnerPosition = i;
                spinnerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                setList(spinnerPosition);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void setList(int position) {

        alCityName = alAllStateCity.get(position).getAlCityName();
        alCity = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < alCityName.size(); i++) {
//                Log.e("City name "," !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"+alCityName.get(i).getStrCity());
            alCity.add(alCityName.get(i).getStrCity());
        }

        cityAdapter = new CityAdapter(context, alCity);
        lvCityList.setAdapter(cityAdapter);
        cityAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
}
```